# UITableView set IndexTitleView to clear color

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have the index title view annoying me see this : [image]

And the code of the subclassed `UITableViewCell`:

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

The damn index is displaying ABOVE the cell I would like to set its backgroundColor to clearColor so I can fill my cell with black !

Thank you very much :)

EDIT : HUm more clear, well this is UITableViewCell and since I have a few sections, I have the index on the right that I can touch to take me go to the section, see the little `1` on the right I would like its view to have a clearColor as background color so the cell will display as fully filled with black !

Comment: can u make your problem statement simple and clear ? It will benefit us to help you out.

Comment: Have you tried changing self.backgroundColor as opposed to contenView.backgroundColor?

Comment: Yes same result sadly :/

Comment: hm, is index an UILabel? Are you setting clear color as its bg?

Comment: I don't know how to access the index itself, it's part of the UITableView class, you can access 2 colors with `sectionIndexColor`  and `sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor` but not the view itself

Comment: Set table's background color to black.

Comment: @rmaddy Actually that works, thank you very much just write an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the background color of a plain table is as simple as:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

There is no need to set the background color of the cells or its contentView.

Answer (score 0):

Set the background of your tableview to black as well.